# How to create multiple threads to populate array optimising processing time

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Hey everyone im having trouble creating threads to populate an array,
The objective is to populate an array in the fastest time possible using pthreads to show parallelisation.

im trying to parallelise this piece of code to increase the speed of the processing time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
}
```

I've tried on making the basic barebones of what you would need in the parallel function however I'm unsure on where to go next from here.

I believe I need to make another function which populates an array to a certain amount and call it in parallel so each thread of that function will speed up the process however since I'm new to c++ I'm unsure on how to do that.

Any advice or resources would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;

#define THREAD 8

struct arg_struct
{
    int *v1, *v2, *v3;
    unsigned long size;
};

int part = 0;

void randomVector(int vector[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //sets a random int value into the vector ith element position
        vector[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}

void *parallel(void *arguments)
{
    struct arg_struct *args = (struct arg_struct *)arguments;
    unsigned long size = args->size;
    int *v1 = args->v1;
    int *v2 = args->v2;
    int *v3 = args->v3;
    
    int thread_part = part++;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    }

}

void somefunction(void *arguments)
{   
    //
}

int main()
{
    struct arg_struct args;
    args.size = 100000000;

    srand(time(0));

    pthread_t threads[THREAD];

    

    //int *v1, *v2, *v3;

    //sets the clock to start by getting the time now
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    //memory alloc is used to dynamically allocate memory with the specified size.
    args.v1 = (int *) malloc(args.size * sizeof(int *));
    args.v2 = (int *) malloc(args.size * sizeof(int *));
    args.v3 = (int *) malloc(args.size * sizeof(int *));


    randomVector(args.v1, args.size);

    randomVector(args.v2, args.size);


    //ToDo: goes in a for loop that will append v3 ith value with v1 + v2
    

    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD; i++) 
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &parallel, NULL);
    }

    pthread_join(threads[THREAD], NULL);

    //gets the start and stop time and subtracts it to get the amount of time spent processing.
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);


    cout << "Time taken by function: " << duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is using the pthread API required? Or are you allowed to use the much nicer `std::thread` API?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please only add related tags. Your code is not valid C code. C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: Consider passing each pthread a copy of `args` that has a different `size` and a different starting point within the `v1`,`v2` and `v3` arrays.

Comment: @Botje I was considering to do that I'm just incapable atm

Comment: why "incapable" ? Do you have c++11 available? `std::thread` is so much easier to use than pthreads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following struct:

```
struct thread_context {
    pthread_t thread;
    int *v1, *v2, *v3;
    unsigned long size;
};
```

You can do the following:

```
thread_context threads[THREAD];
for (int i = 0; i < THREAD; i++) {
    int part_size = size / THREAD;
    int part_offset = part_size * i;
    threads[i] = { 0, &v1[part_offset], &v2[part_offset], &v3[part_offset], part_size };
    pthread_create(&threads[i].thread, NULL, &parallel, &threads[i]);
}
```

With the `std::thread` API you can do this much nicer: (assuming `parallel` takes some extra parameters)

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (int i = 0; i < THREAD; i++) {
    threads.emplace_back(&parallel, &v1[part_offset], &v2[part_offset], &v3[part_offset], part_size);
}
```

Comment: so i tried it out and it gives me an error at &v1[part_offset] and at the rest that they are undefined

Comment: Well, yes. Your original code put `v1`,`v2`, and `v3` inside the `args` local variable. I assume these are now local variables, since there is no point to keeping an `args` around that you're not going to use. If you can't be arsed to do that, just change to `&args.v1[...]` etc.

Comment: yeah all good fixed it by creating a default struct